# File list is not rendered in typo3 frontend

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

After updating from TYPO3 4.5 to 6.2, File lists are not rendered in the frontend anymore.

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0
page.stylesheet = fileadmin/template/design.css
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20 {
template = FILE
template.file = fileadmin/template/templ.html
workOnSubpart = document
subparts.cont = CONTENT
subparts.cont {
     table = tt_content
     select.orderBy = sorting
     select.where = colPos = 0
    }
```

This is the TypoScript Setup I was using before; it should the standard rendering routine for Text (that is working) and Images (this is working as well), but for some reason there's only an empty `ul` block:

```
    <!--  File list: [begin] -->
        <ul class="csc-uploads csc-uploads-0"></ul>
    <!--  File list: [end] -->
```

I don't know what is going wrong...

Comment: If you edit the filelist CE in the BE the files are shown?

Comment: Yes, the files are visible in the backend, but not rendered in the frontend, thus, assuming an typoscript issue... I updated the DB and the reference index, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. TYPO3 was still set to run "as TYPO3 4.5" compatibility mode. Going through the Upgrade wizard again and finally use TYPO3 6.2, everything is now working.

Bottom line: TYPO3 4.5 compatibility mode is not actual producing the same output as TYPO3 4.5!